# How to get / store value in different variables from same request for different scenarios

Tags: jmeter

def Scenario = vars.get("Scenario")

[image]

I'm using above code in JSR233 Pre-Processer to run three different scenarios and executed successfully.

JSON Response:
**{"data":"qf13tm2DCCaq0r3HJ0EIVHXT7","success":true,"statusCode":200}**

I'm trying to save Json response value[data] for each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save different variables values you need to use different variables names like:

```
if (scenario.contains('Today')) {
    vars.put('Starttime_today', 'your_value_here')
}
else if (scenario.contains('Future')) {
    vars.put('Starttime_future', 'your_future_value_here')
}
//etc
```

Couple more hints:

1. You might want to use [switch](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_switch_case) operator instead of multiple [ifs](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_if_else)
2. If you inline [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts **only first value** will be compiled and cached so when you run your test with multiple iterations you won't get the new value

More information:

- [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Ivan I was trying to save JSON response value which is data.

Comment: In order to save a part of response data into a JMeter Variable you need a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors). Normally people use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)  for this but if you like Groovy you can do it using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as well, example code: `vars.put('data',new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data)`